# redirecting the requests to a different server

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection

I have a scenario like this.

i have lot of space to store data but I dont have the super user permission to install a server. So I am thinking of buying a server space and install a apache server and store the files in my local server. I do not know how I can do this. Can anybody give me some direction.I am using linux OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Even budget hosts will give you a 250GB or bigger hard drive with a dedicated server... is that not enough space to store the files on the web server?

Comment: I am a student and I cannot get the root permissions on the university servers and the dedicated servers too are costly.

Comment: Why did you write "I am thinking of buying..." if you can't afford to buy one?

Comment: I was saying about web hosting service not a dedicated server

Comment: How would the web host access the files on your local server to use them?

Comment: I thought of buying space on web hosting companies like bluehost, install apache server on it and use my university server space to store data

Comment: OK, if the "data" is going to be stored on your university server, and you have web hosting from a company like bluehost, why do you mention the two things in the same question. It makes one assume they're related somehow (that the "data" you want to store is "data" you want to serve through a web server), but if they're going to be on two different computers, then there is no connection... I can't set up a web server that serves data from your PC, that'd be crazy, I have no access to your things... just like Bluehost can't serve data from your PC...

Answer (score 1):

You could do all sorts of things, including proxying, but the professional solution to the problem of "I don't have permission to install a server" is "get permission".  Make a business case for why the server and/or storage space is necessary, and take it to the people who make the decisions.  Deploying a deeply sub-optimal solution isn't the way to solve your problem.

Comment: As I am a student they will not give root permissions to the university servers

Comment: So this isn't related to the "manage[ment] or maintain[ance of] computers in a professional capacity"?  Then it's not appropriate for this site.